# How to properly define a robots.txt file for a wordpress placed in a subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt, subdirectory

I have a problem related with robots.txt file.

I have a website with an HTML landing page that can bring Access to a wordpress blog wich is placed in a subfolder. Here's an example of the structure:

- http/domain/index.html
- http/domain/blog/indexblog.html

First of all I though that maybe the solution was to place the robots.txt file on the /blog folder, but it doesn't work because google doesn't recognize it. As far as I know the robots.txt file must be placed at the root folder, like this:

- http/domain/robots.txt

because if you place it like this it will not be recognized by google:

- http/domain/blog/robots.txt

Then I thought that maybe it was as simple of including the complete path at the robots.txt file. So this is the original robots.txt file for wordpress:

```
User-agent:  *
# disallow all files in these directories
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /archives/
disallow: /*?*
Disallow: *?replytocom
Disallow: /wp-*
Disallow: /comments/feed/
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Allow: /
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/

User-agent: Adsbot-Google
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Allow: /
```

And this is how I define it by adding the /blog to the path:

```
User-agent:  *
    # disallow all files in these directories
    Disallow: /blog/cgi-bin/
    Disallow: /blog/wp-admin/
    Disallow: /blog/archives/
    disallow: /blog/*?*
    Disallow: /blog/*?replytocom
    Disallow: /blog/wp-*
    Disallow: /blog/comments/feed/
    User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
    Allow: /blog/
    User-agent: Googlebot-Image
    Allow: /blog/wp-content/uploads/

    User-agent: Adsbot-Google
    Allow: /blog/

    User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
    Allow: /blog/
```

However when I checked the code at google-webmastertools, it was modified to the previous code...

So, what is the solution for that situation?

thank you!

** ------ EDIT ------ **

Maybe my post was a bit confusing and that's why nobody could gave me the answer. So I will remake the question...

I have a website with a simple HTML landing index page placed at the root folder and then a wordpress placed at the /blog subfolder.

**I just need to know how should I indicate on robots.txt that there are some subfolders from the wordpress that must not be indexed.**

For example: */blog/wp-admin subfolder...*

Which is the correct way to indicate this path at the robots.txt file?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the indention intended?

Comment: Hi rudi, the idea is to allow indexation of the usual articles, categories, pictures, etc but the usual standard "admin" folders should not be indexed...

Comment: I understand. My question is why you've intended all the lines after the first one. I am not sure if this is a problem, but I've never seen that before. Next thing: you should add a blank line before every "User-agent:" directive.

Comment: "However when I checked the code at google-webmastertools, it was modified to the previous code": What does that mean? Google Webmaster Tools can’t modify your robots.txt, right?

Comment: Hi Rudi, sorry I not sure what do you mean with "intended". The robots.txt code was obtained from a blog were there is a tutorial of how to add an optimized robots.txt file to a wordpress website. So I copied it. Hi Unor, at webmastertools there is an option to check your robots.txt code. So the tool allows you to paste your robots.txt code and send it to google to check if it is OK. Then it allows you to copy a returned code. I commit a mistake because I thouhg it has modified the code back but I see that the code was not modified. So now the code has '/blog'. is that way correct?

Comment: You have spaces at the beginning of each line. That is untypical and I don't know, whether bots could have a problem with it. I would remove them..